# Copying a folder, but excluding specified sub-directories

Tags: command-line, scripting, batch-file, cmd, dos

I need help with copying a folder, but doesn't copy sub-folders with the names that are specified in a text file. The text file is located:

> U:\Directory\Directory\Textfile.txt

I need to copy folders that are specified in the text file, but here's the catch, after

`U:\Directory\Directory\` the folders have random names, which is why they are stored in the text file. Example of what the directory tree looks like:

> U:\Directory\Directory\"12345"\Pickle <--- Pickle is the folder I want.
>
> U:\Directory\Directory\"22345"\Pickle
>
> ```
>                      ^ 
>                      |
> ```
>
> This is a random name specified in the text file.

They all have the folder `Pickle` inside, which is what I'm after. Inside the text file are names of all the folders that are after: `U:\Directory\Directory\`. The text file looks like this:

> 1335232                  <--- This is the name of the random folders.
>
> 1242334                  <--- They all are located:
>
> 2342312                  <--- U:\Directory\Directory\~HERE~
>
> (etc...)

The folders should be copied from `U:\Directory\Directory\"12345"\Pickle to U:\Output\`

The names for all folders are numbers if this helps. Thank you Peter for trying to help me, I'm sorry if I was unclear. I hope this clears things up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET relroot=u:\directory
SET subdir=randomsubfoldername
::
FOR /f %%i IN (
  'dir /b /ad %relroot%\%subdir% ^|findstr /b /e /v /g:textfile.txt '
    ) DO ECHO %relroot%\%subdir%\%%i
```

The `DIR` command lists the directorynames (`/ad`) in basic form (`.b`) - that is, name-only. The `findstr` finds lines that do not (`/v`) begin (`/b`) and end (`/e`) with the lines in the file filename (`/g:filename`)

---

With the revised information, and noting that the original information clearly showed the penultimate directory name was the same and selection occurring on the leaf, and the single example now provided...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO Here is a test structure
ECHO -----------------------------
DIR /s /b /ad u:\directory
ECHO ------Here is the textfile---------
TYPE u:\directory\textfile.txt
ECHO ====Method 1==============
FOR /f %%i IN (u:\directory\textfile.txt) DO (
DIR /s /b /ad u:\directory | FINDSTR /r ".*\\%%i\\.*" | FINDSTR /v /r ".*\\%%i\\.*\\.*"
)

ECHO ====Method 2==============
FOR /f %%i IN (u:\directory\textfile.txt) DO (
 FOR /f %%s IN (
  'DIR /s /b /ad u:\directory ^| FINDSTR /r ".*\\%%i\\.*" ^| FINDSTR /v /r ".*\\%%i\\.*\\.*"'
 ) DO ECHO selected : %%s
)


ECHO ====Method 3 - to ignore ...\target\subdir that has any subdir ==============
FOR /f %%i IN (u:\directory\textfile.txt) DO (
 FOR /f %%s IN (
  'DIR /s /b /ad u:\directory ^| FINDSTR /r ".*\\%%i\\.*" ^| FINDSTR /v /r ".*\\%%i\\.*\\.*"'
 ) DO (
 FOR /f %%c IN ( 'DIR /a:d %%s ^|FIND /c "<" ' ) DO IF %%c==2 ECHO SELECTED : %%s
 )
)
```

Here's the run results:

```
Here is a test structure
-----------------------------
u:\directory\another
u:\directory\yetanother
u:\directory\572
u:\directory\another\yetanother
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572
u:\directory\another\yetanother\1572
u:\directory\another\yetanother\5722
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\wantthis
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\andthis
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\maywantthisidontknow
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\572
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\maywantthisidontknow\ignore
u:\directory\another\yetanother\1572\ignorethis
u:\directory\another\yetanother\5722\ignorethis
u:\directory\yetanother\572
u:\directory\yetanother\572\wantthis
u:\directory\572\wantthis
------Here is the textfile---------
23
753309
572
====Method 1==============
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\wantthis
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\andthis
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\maywantthisidontknow
u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\572
u:\directory\yetanother\572\wantthis
u:\directory\572\wantthis
====Method 2==============
selected : u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\wantthis
selected : u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\andthis
selected : u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\maywantthisidontknow
selected : u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\572
selected : u:\directory\yetanother\572\wantthis
selected : u:\directory\572\wantthis
====Method 3 - to ignore ...\target\subdir that has any subdir ==============
SELECTED : u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\wantthis
SELECTED : u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\andthis
SELECTED : u:\directory\another\yetanother\572\572
SELECTED : u:\directory\yetanother\572\wantthis
SELECTED : u:\directory\572\wantthis
```

The two `FINDSTR` regex structures are

```
FINDSTR /r ".*\\%%i\\.*"
```

Any number of any characters, `\`, the target string, `\`, any number of any characters

```
FINDSTR /v /r ".*\\%%i\\.*\\.*"
```

Any number of any characters, `\`, the target string, `\`, any number of any characters,`\`, any number of any characters

BUT - the `/v` on FINDSTR means **except** lines matching...

---

I can make little sense of `copy the sub-folder from a parent folder with a random name.`

If the requirement is to copy into the selected directory from that directory's parent directory, then after verifying that the target directories being displayed by `ECHO SELECTED : %%s` replace `ECHO SELECTED : %%s` with

```
(
pushd %%s
xcopy ..\* . >nul
popd
)
```

The `>nul` suppresses xcopy reports

If it means something else, more information is required.

Comment: The folders located after `U:\Directory\ ` aren't named properly, they're named with a variable that makes the folder name with numbers. However the folder names are stored in a text file, with a new line for each folder located in `U:\Directory\Textfile.txt` . Again, the folders with a random name are located after `U:\Directory` .

Comment: Best to edit your original question and provide some realistic examples. What do you mean by "named properly?" For instance, do you have `U:\Directory\12345\98765`, `U:\Directory\12345\54321` and know "12345" by some means, or do you have `U:\Directory\12345\98765`, `U:\Directory\12345\54321` and `U:\Directory\98765\54321`? Which combination do you want? What about `U:\Directory\nonnumeric\54321`? What is in your file to make the selection, and which directory/ies do you want selected?

Comment: The directory looks like this:

`U:\Directory\EvenMoreDirectory\1928753\FolderIWant`

`U:\Directory\EvenMoreDirectory\2342342\FolderIWant`

The folders names are in a text file located:

`U:\Directory\EvenMoreDirectory\Textfile.txt`

Comment: So you got it to echo all this stuff, but I need it to copy.